# Is there a better way to initialize Cubit from ObjectDB then using Constructor in BlocProvider?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to create initialization function placed inside Cubit class (something that works alike initState() {} from State<>) to divide my UI classes from business logic classes. Is there a way to call internal function in Cubit extending class from super() part of constructor to initialize from DB or I can only use State extending class to create needed Cubit in BlocProvider?

Answer (score 1):

The common good practice is to run some initiative function when providing the cubit to a widget using the `..` operator. So in the `create` parameter to the `BlocProvider` you do something like this:

```
create: (_) => YourCubit()..initializingMethod(),
```

Comment: Can I use factory constructor for this?

Comment: Sure, just do as you do today when you provide the cubit to a widget. The only difference is that you call the `initializingMethod()` straight right away upon creation of the cubit. This keeps the cubit (possible) more testable than if you do a lot of logic in the constructor.